# No muestra en la vista un dato de la consulta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Estoy trabajando con C# ASP.NET MVC5, soy nueva en esta tecnología, estoy realizando un apágina web donde necesito mostrar en la vista datos provenientes de tres tablas, les muestro la estructura de la base de datos.

**tabla registro**

```
|-----------------|-------------------|------------|
|  id_registro    |        2          |  3         |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------|
| fecha_registro  |     2017-05-21    | 2017-05-26 |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------|
| evento          | Aumento del valor | Disminuye  |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------|
|  id_pais        |       1           |   5
```

**Tabla Pais (n_pais)**

```
| id_pais   |     1   |  5    |
|-----------|---------|-------|
|   pais    | Austria | India |
|-----------|---------|-------|
| id_region |   4     |   3   |
```

**Tabla Region (n_region)**

```
| id_region | 3    |    4    |
|-----------|------|---------|
| region    | Mali | Venecia |
```

En la vista lo que deseo mostrar es:

```
Registro      Fecha        Evento             Pais      Region

  2           2017-05-21   Aumento del valor  Austria   Venecia
  3           2017-05-26   Disminuye          India     Mali
```

**El código en la vista**

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id_registro
    </th>
    <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fecha_registro)
    </th>
    <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.evento)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.n_pais.pais)
    </th>
    <th>
       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.n_region.region)
    </th>

</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id_registro)
           </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fecha_registro)
            </td>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.evento)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.n_pais.pais)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.n_region.region)
        </td>
      </tr>
    }

</table>
```

**El controlador**
    *La consulta en SQL*

```
SELECT * FROM registro, n_pais, n_region
WHERE registro.id_pais = n_pais.id_pais AND
      n_pais.id_region = n_region.id_region
```

*LinQ*

```
var query = from q in db.registro
             join r in db.n_pais on q.id_pais equals r.id_pais
             join m in db.n_region on r.id_region equals m.id_region
             select q;
 return View(query.ToList());
```

En la vista se ven los resultados de la tabla registro y de país, sin embargo de la región se queda vacío. Qué puedo hacer, en que me equivoqué?

Comment: @Xique yo la debugueo y veo, a mi entender, que tiene los datos que necesito, pero no me muestra valores de la region

Comment: pero ahi solo retornas la entidad q(Registro) que no tiene relación directa con Región, en esta parte ->@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.n_region.region) seria -> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.n_pais.n_region.region)

Comment: creo que si, a veces si otras no.

Comment: +1, me funciono con @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.n_pais.n_region.region)

Comment: bueno entonces añado eso a mi respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que Registro no tiene relación directa con Región en esta parte deberías cambiar 
->

`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.n_region.region)` 
por -> `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.n_pais.n_region.region)`

Aunque otra posible solución para evitar ese código tan extenso en la vista puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

La clase que tendrías que agregar seria mas o menos así :

```
public class DatosMostrar
{
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Evento { get; set; }
    public string Pais { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
}
```

para poder asignarle los datos de la consulta que tienes

y ya la consulta en tu método quedaría de la siguiente manera, asignándole los valores de la misma a la clase antes creada

```
 var query = from q in db.registro
             join r in db.n_pais on q.id_pais equals r.id_pais
             join m in db.n_region on r.id_region equals m.id_region
             select new DatosMostrar  
             {
              Registro =q.id_registro,
              Fecha = q.fecha_registro,
              Evento = q.evento 
              Pais = r.pais,
              Region  = m.region
             };
```

y ya en la vista cambiarías `IEnumerable<TuProyecto.Models.registro>` por `IEnumerable<TuProyecto.Models.DatosMostrar>`

y plasmarías los datos así:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Registro)
           </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fecha)
            </td>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Evento)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pais)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Region)
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Datos a mostrar seria una clase Modelo?

Comment: si, la puedes nombrar como te convenga